# sort contact list and store output in JSON using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, data-structures

I have a contact list file "input.txt" and I want to sort by LastName, FirstName. the file also has a favorite color and zip code.

Contents of this file are structured as follows:

```
LastName, FirstName, (123)-123-1234, Blue, 11013
FirstName LastName, Green, 12345, 123 123 1234
FirstName, LastName, 12345, 123 123 1234, Yellow
```

input.txt:

```
Annalee Loftis, green, 74339, 360 105 7811
Quinton, Liptak, 87225, 194 974 1020, yellow
Demming, Kent, (753)-851-4445, blue, 81403
Humperdink, Englebert G., (232)-955-1267, aqua marine, 28278
Corliss Nurse, green, 123123121, 640 163 2354
```

Here is what I have coded so far in python 3.

```
import os
import string
import re
f = open("input.txt", "r")
for i in f:
  if i and i[0].isalpha(): // proccess lines that starts with alphabet
    a = str((i.split(", ")))
    print(a)
```

Now, how Do I sort by lastname, firstname and output in JSON?

Thank you.

Comment: Your code doesn't even determine where the different parts of the name *are*.

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom `key` function for the builtin function `sorted()`. The parsing is done through `re` module.

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

# the last and first name table:
# LastName, FirstName, (123)-123-1234, Blue, 11013
# FirstName LastName, Green, 12345, 123 123 1234
# FirstName, LastName, 12345, 123 123 1234, Yellow

data = """
Annalee Loftis, green, 74339, 360 105 7811
Quinton, Liptak, 87225, 194 974 1020, yellow
Demming, Kent, (753)-851-4445, blue, 81403
Humperdink, Englebert G., (232)-955-1267, aqua marine, 28278
Corliss Nurse, green, 123123121, 640 163 2354"""

g = re.findall(r'^(.*?), (.*?), (.*?), (.*?)$', data, flags=re.M)

def get_first_last(v):    
    if v[1].lower() == 'green':
        first_name, last_name = v[0].split()
    elif v[-1].lower() == 'yellow':
        first_name, last_name = v[0], v[1]
    else:
        first_name, last_name = v[1], v[0]

    return last_name, first_name

pprint(sorted(g, key=lambda v: get_first_last(v)))
```

This will print:

```
[('Demming', 'Kent', '(753)-851-4445', 'blue, 81403'),
 ('Humperdink', 'Englebert G.', '(232)-955-1267', 'aqua marine, 28278'),
 ('Annalee Loftis', 'green', '74339', '360 105 7811'),
 ('Corliss Nurse', 'green', '123123121', '640 163 2354'),
 ('Quinton', 'Liptak', '87225', '194 974 1020, yellow')]
```

To output the list as Json you could do:

```
sorted_data = (sorted(g, key=lambda v: get_first_last(v)))
pprint(json.dumps(sorted_data, indent=4))
```

Which prints:

```
('[\n'
 '    [\n'
 '        "Demming",\n'
 '        "Kent",\n'
 '        "(753)-851-4445",\n'
 '        "blue, 81403"\n'
 '    ],\n'
 '    [\n'
 '        "Humperdink",\n'
 '        "Englebert G.",\n'
 '        "(232)-955-1267",\n'
 '        "aqua marine, 28278"\n'
 '    ],\n'
 '    [\n'
 '        "Annalee Loftis",\n'
 '        "green",\n'
 '        "74339",\n'
 '        "360 105 7811"\n'
 '    ],\n'
 '    [\n'
 '        "Corliss Nurse",\n'
 '        "green",\n'
 '        "123123121",\n'
 '        "640 163 2354"\n'
 '    ],\n'
 '    [\n'
 '        "Quinton",\n'
 '        "Liptak",\n'
 '        "87225",\n'
 '        "194 974 1020, yellow"\n'
 '    ]\n'
 ']')
```